# How can I add a custom module to be loaded globally in AlloyUI?

Tags: liferay-6, alloy-ui

I have written a custom module that works fine as part of main.js and would like to move it to a separate file. I am using liferay 6.1 GA3.

I have tried to add the following in main.js with no success:

```
YUI.GlobalConfig = ({
    modules: {
        'bb-select-detail': {
            fullpath: '/js/selectDetail.js',
            requires:["aui-base", "aui-loading-mask", "aui-io-request", "json-parse", "oop", "aui-parse-content"]
        }
    }
});
```

Many thanks,
Alain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with [applyConfig](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/YUI.html#method_applyConfig) instead?

```
YUI.applyConfig({
    modules: {
        'bb-select-detail': {
            fullpath: '/js/selectDetail.js',
            requires:["aui-base", "aui-loading-mask", "aui-io-request", "json-parse", "oop", "aui-parse-content"]
        }
    }
});
```

You can use it both statically to apply to all YUI instances, or on a given instance.

Comment: What worked in my main.js is AUI().applyConfig( [...] fullpath: '/bamboost-project-portlet/js/selectDetail.js' [...]). Thanks.
Any idea how I can get the contextPath in main.js instead of hardcoding bamboost-project-portlet ?